# When I create pdf with itextg from ListView only the same listview child appears

Tags: image, listview, pdf, itext

I am trying to create a pdf from listview items. This is my listview:
[image: Image1]

This is the result:
[image: Image2]

Below is my code:

```
ListView def = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ist);
ListAdapter adapter = def.getAdapter();
int itemscount = adapter.getCount();
/*int itemsposition = adapter.getItem(position);*/
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemscount + " temaxia", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
int allitemsheight = 0;
List<Bitmap> bmps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

for (int i = 0; i < itemscount ; i++) {
    View childView = adapter.getView(i, null, def);
    /*View childView = def.getChildAt(1);*/
    childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(def.getWidth(),
        View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(),
        childView.getMeasuredHeight());
    childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    childView.buildDrawingCache();
    childView.getDrawingCache();
    /*bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());
    allitemsheight+=childView.getMeasuredHeight();*/
    Bitmap bigbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(def.getMeasuredWidth(),
        childView.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bigbitmap);
    def.draw(bigcanvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bigbitmap,0,childView.getMeasuredHeight(),paint);
    bigbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
    myImg.scalePercent(45, 60);
    myImg.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);

    // add image to document
    doc.add(myImg);
    doc.add( new Paragraph());
}
```

I just cant find why it only gets childview in first position despite it is inside a for loop. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed all the consept to: Create a big image from all childviews and then cut it to multiple pages A4 size.See below....NOTICE that first doc is never opened and never closed,but after creating image document is opened and closed properly ...............
                        File file = new File(dir, flname + ".pdf");
                        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        FileOutputStream fOut2 = new FileOutputStream(file);

```
                    pdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

                    // open the document
                   /* doc.open();*/
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    //////////////////////

                    ListView def = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ist);


                    ListAdapter adapter = def.getAdapter();
                    int itemscount = adapter.getCount();
                    /*int itemsposition = adapter.getItem(position);*/
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemscount + " temaxia", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    View childView =null;
                    int allitemsheight = 0;

                    List<Bitmap> bmps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < itemscount ; i++) {
                        childView = adapter.getView(i,null,def);
                        /*childView = def.getChildAt(i);*/
                        childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(def.getWidth(),
                                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                        childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                                childView.getMeasuredHeight());
                        childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                        childView.buildDrawingCache();
                        /*childView.getDrawingCache();*/
                        bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());

                        allitemsheight+=childView.getMeasuredHeight();

                    }
                    Bitmap bigbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(def.getMeasuredWidth(),
                            allitemsheight , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bigbitmap);

                    for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
                        Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
                        bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
                        /*bigcanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                        def.draw(bigcanvas);*/

                        iHeight+=bmp.getHeight();
                        bmp.recycle();
                        bmp=null;


                    }
                    bigbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                    Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                    myImg.scalePercent(45, 60);
                    myImg.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);



                    /*if(myImg.getWidth() >= doc.getPageSize().getWidth() || myImg.getHeight() >= doc.getPageSize().getHeight()){
                        myImg.scaleToFit(doc.getPageSize());
                        doc.newPage();
                    }
                    myImg.setAbsolutePosition((doc.getPageSize().getWidth() - myImg.getScaledWidth()) / BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_MEDIUM, (doc.getPageSize().getHeight() - myImg.getScaledHeight()) / BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_MEDIUM);

                    doc.add(myImg);
                    doc.add( new Paragraph());*/


                    ///////////////////////////////////////
                    /////////////////////////////////////////
                    /////////////////////////////////////
                    Document document = new Document();
                    PdfWriter pdfWriter2 = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fOut2);

                    document.open();

                    PdfContentByte content = pdfWriter2.getDirectContent();
                    myImg.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4);
                    myImg.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

                    float width = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
                    float heightRatio = myImg.getHeight() * width / myImg.getWidth();
                    int nPages = (int) (heightRatio / PageSize.A4.getHeight());
                    float difference = heightRatio % PageSize.A4.getHeight();

                    while (nPages >= 0) {
                        document.newPage();
                        content.addImage(myImg, width, 0, 0, heightRatio, 0, -((--nPages * PageSize.A4.getHeight()) + difference));
                    }
                    document.close();



                } catch (DocumentException de) {
                    Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
                } finally {
                    /*doc.close();*/
                }
```